# What is this shape ? $|x|+|y|+|z|=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is this shape ? $|x|+|y|+|z|=1$ I thought it might be a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but don't really know how to determine this...

Comment: A sphere would be $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Look at $|x|+|y|=1$ in the plane.

Comment: an octahedron, anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an octahedron.  I figured it out by thinking about slices of the $xy$ plane: when $z=0$ we have a (rotated) square shape, and for other values of $z$ this shape is smaller to account for the contribution of $\vert z \vert$.  At $z = \pm 1$ it becomes a single point.

It is maybe worth noting that it *is* a sphere if you use an [alternative notion of distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).  If you square the terms instead of taking the absolute value then you get an ordinary sphere instead.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that in the positive octant $x,y,z\ge0$ the equation is equivalent to $x+y+z=1$, which leads to the equilateral triangle with vertices at $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$. By symmetry we have a shape with eight equilateral triangles and six vertices lying on the coordinate axes.

Comment: That is more convincing than my explanation.  Even without matching up the vertices it makes it obvious that there are $8$ faces.

Comment: many thanks mate...I don't know if it's true but it sounds right